# NSURLConnection is not downloading files with spaces in the name

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, filenames, nsurl

I am working on loading images into a gallery on the iPhone and running into an issue.  It is apparent that something in the script isn't happy with spaces being in filename's when trying to download the images off of the internet.

This is the connection line.

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]] delegate:self];
```

And I pass an NSString in the NSURL.  It works on all photos that don't have spaces.

Example of evil photos:
thumbs_WJ (16).jpg
thumbs_WJ (25).jpg

Now I know I could go back and update all the photos, update the database, and change the script so it doesn't add spaces anymore...but we are talking about thousands of photos.

And suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to do string:

```
str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method on the text you want to include as an argument.

From [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:):

> stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
>
> Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

If your string is a "normal" string, you can use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as encoding. Otherwise, specify the encoding your string is in.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace spaces with "%20" in your urlstring.